# REST HDFS API for HDFS Encryption Process

Tags: rest, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I want to create encrypted zone using WebHDFS. Below is command for which i am looking for its REST implementation .

```
hdfs crypto -createZone -keyName myKey -path /zone
```

Can someone point me documentation/examaple for same?

Comment: did you find any solution for this ? if not please share your approach like how did you do this using code or any other approach which you took.

Comment: @saching I could not find any REST api but there are Java API available for doing this. 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api//org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/client/HdfsAdmin.html#createEncryptionZone-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-java.lang.String-java.util.EnumSet-